# How to create buttons from Javascript array, linked to google maps markers?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, button

I have a map populated with markers from an array. When the markers are clicked they send data to an HTML text box with address data from the array, Like this;

```
    document.getElementById("address_box").value = title;

    <input type = "text" id = "address_box" value = ""/>
```

This is the code used to populate the markers

```
  for (var i = 0; i < arrMarkers.length; i++) {
        latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(arrMarkers[i].lat, arrMarkers[i].lng);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng, 
            map: map, 
            title: arrMarkers[i].title,
             icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png"
        });
```

**I'd like to use another for loop to create buttons dynamically on the page that use the matching array index of each marker.**

As I understand it, I should perhaps just send the array index and title to the button so data can be pulled from the array and sent to the text box.

Here is some pseudo-code I've written. I imagine that I'd need some html to receive it too.

```
 for (var i = 0; i < arrMarkers.length; i++) {
        button = newButton(arrMarkers[i].title);
      });
```

**What code can I use to add a  button outside to the page outside of the javascript?**

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Do you mean form input buttons? Or form submisson buttons? Not entirely sure what you are asking. But if submit type buttons, you could just add to the form from within each loop through the marker setting code. No need for a seperate loop.

Comment: just submit buttons that highlight the markers.

Comment: @Rafe How would I add to the form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On reflection, you wouldn't even need a form for it. For this example, an unordered list with the id of "addresses" would work better.

```
for (var i = 0; i < arrMarkers.length; i++) {

    document.getElementById('addresses').innerHTML += '<li><a href="javascript:show(' + i + ');return false">' + arrMarkers[i].title + '</a></li>';

    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(arrMarkers[i].lat, arrMarkers[i].lng);
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng, 
        map: map, 
        title: arrMarkers[i].title,
         icon: "http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/micons/blue.png"
    });
```

Then you would just need to write a function to show the requested marker if you wish to do that.

I had the old code for v2 but that would be pretty useless here. There must be a show function in the v3 marker managers.

Comment: Excellent response. Thank you!

Comment: I've written a function like this to test it.
function show(i)
{
alert(i);
} 

but it doesn't output anything

Comment: Ok I moved it lower down the code and now it works for some reason.